# unrecognized selector sent to instance to a newly added method; messages to previously defined methods work fine

Tags: ios

'-[MTviewFilesVC launchVF]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e59fcd0'

I added a method to a class but calling it creates 'unrecognized selector' run time error
The calling code is:

```
self.viewFilesVCPtr = [[MTviewFilesVC alloc] init];
[self.viewFilesVCPtr launchVF];
```

This works if, for example, I substitute viewDidLoad which exists already hence I
think the calling code is OK.Is there something else I need to add to the declaration of lanuchVF
to make it visible?

The method declaration, etc is:

.h:

```
#import "DirectoryWatcher.h"

@interface MTviewFilesVC : UITableViewController   <QLPreviewControllerDataSource,
                                                    QLPreviewControllerDelegate,
                                                    DirectoryWatcherDelegate,
                                                    UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
-(IBAction)saveViewFiles;
- (void)launchVF;

@end
```

.m:

```
@interface MTviewFilesVC ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) DirectoryWatcher *docWatcher;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *documentURLs;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDocumentInteractionController *viewFileController;
-(void) launchVF;
@end

...

- (void)lanuchVF
{
    UIStoryboard *settingsStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                        @"viewFiles" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initialViewFilesVC = [settingsStoryBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    initialViewFilesVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:initialViewFilesVC animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method name in the .m has a typo, `lanuchVF` instead of `launchVF` :-)

Comment: This should have been a compiler warning that you're implementation was incomplete. This is a good reason to keep your project warning free.